# Firebase email and password authentication Python

Tags: python, firebase, authentication

I would like to use the firebase database in my python program and restrict certain information to certain users. I have figured out how to set up the rules but would like to implement the authentication part into my program. I have imported:

```
from firebase import firebase
```

And I have a user: test.user@gmail.com pass: password123

how can would I make a post request that verifies that this user can indeed post?

Answer (score 0):

You are able to create custom `Security Rules` and verify users permissions with `Custom Claims`.

Check this [tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) for more information

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to first create a firestore "collection" keyed by user_id containing the claims.  Then you can decorate your restricted methods to require a valid idToken plus arbitrary conditions on the claims:

```
import firebase_admin
import firebase_fave


# wrapper function to require credentials and claims!
def require_creds(creds_reqs={}):

    def real_require_creds(protected_function):

        @wraps(protected_function)
        def protector(*args, **kwargs):
            token = request.args.get('idToken', '')
            try:
                auth_resp = firebase_admin.auth.verify_id_token(token, check_revoked=True)
                claims = firebase_admin.firestore.client().collection('user_claims')\
                    .document(auth_resp['user_id']).get().to_dict()
            except:
                abort(401)

            if 'exp' in auth_resp\
                    and auth_resp['exp'] > time.time()\
                    and min(*[bool(creds_reqs[k](v)) for k, v in claims.items()]):
                return protected_function(*args, **kwargs)
            else:
                abort(401)

        return protector

    return real_require_creds
```

## Usage:

```
@require_creds(
    {'access_flag': lambda x: x & 8, 'release_lag', lambda x: time.time() > RELEASE_TIME + x}
  )
def your_post_method(self, ...
```

See also my monkey patch on pypi that adds a verify_user method to firebase_admin: 
https://pypi.org/project/firebase_fave/